# how to getTime in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to convert code from as2 to as3.

```
timeFaktor = 4;

function timeReset() {
    delete curretnTime;
    delete showtTime;
    currentTime = new Date();
    showTime = new Date();
    startingTime = false;
    pauseTime = 0;
    txt_Time.text = "t = "+0+" s";
}

function moveTime() {
    delete currentTime;
    currentTime = new Date();
    if (!startingTime) {
        starTime = currentTime.getTime();
        startingTime= true;
    }
    newTime = Number(currentTime.getTime()-starTimeMulai)+Number(pauseTime);
    secon = newSecon/1000;
    time = (Math.round(detik*100))/100;
    txt_time.text = "t = "+time+" s";
}
```

Comment: _"I want you to check that my code is correct..."_ What **exactly** are we checking for? Show us the AS3 version code that you've tried to make & ask one **specific** Question about your code issue...

Comment: It's correct if it does what you want it to. But since you haven't described what you want it to do then we can't answer this question. As for AS2 to AS3, I don't see anything in your code that would be different between the two versions but AS2 was a long time ago for me so I can't be sure. But there are no glaring syntactic errors in your code that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

It's just saying that `ketapel1` is not a function but you are treating it as one by trying to pass it parameters.

```
ketaple1(parameter1, parameter2, ...);
```

Flash sees this and says "son is trying to pass parameters to this thing like it's a function" and throws the error.

The second error is saying that `Xo` hasn't been defined. Which it looks like it hasn't. Define those values outside any other functions.

Since I don't know what Xo or ketaple is I can't help more than that